# Asymptotic analysis with affine relations

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

I have very little experience with asymptotics so would appreciate some help.

I have a function $g$ and I have an asymptotic to a rational function: $g\sim r$. I guess I can just take the highest powers above and below and so I have $\displaystyle g\sim \frac{1}{N^4}$ but what I actually have is $\displaystyle g\sim \frac{(N-4)!}{N!}$ via:
$$1<\dfrac{g(N)}{(N-4)!/N!}<\frac{N-2}{N-3}.$$

Now I have another function $f$ that is related to $g$ by:

$$f(N)+(N-3)g(N)=\frac{1}{N(N-1)(N-2)}.$$

Can I figure out the asymptotics for for $f$ from this? Naively I get $f\sim 0$ but that seems a bit iffy. Actually very very iffy because naively putting in the two different asymptotes gives different answers.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you need the next term in the expansion for $g$. ie $ g \sim (N-4)!/n! + (?)$. You are correct that the relation $f \sim 0$ is not acceptable: things can't be asymptotic to zero

Comment: If $g \sim (n-4)/n!$ as $n \to \infty$ then $g=(n-4)/n!+G$ where $G<<(n-4)/n!$. Substituting this into the expression for $f$ we get $f=G/(n-3)$. Put another way, $f$ *is* the next to leading order term in the large $n$ expansion of $g(n-3)$

Comment: @Sal sorry that last (now deleted) comment was erroneous. Correct information about $g$ added to question..